# Preventing document Uploading to Document Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: event-handlers

Here is my scenario.

I would like to allow the only certain file types (doc,docx,pdf,ppt,pptx) into my document library.  I wrote an `ItemAdding` event receiver for a document library as follows. But I am unable to prevent the uploading. Can someone guide me?

```
{
    checking the file type here.
}

properties.Cancel = true;
//properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.ErrorMessage = "File extension not allowed here";
// properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("Invalid File Type");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You have to do following:

```
        properties.RedirectUrl = properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl +
          "/_layouts/settings.aspx";
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
properties.Cancel = true;
```

Or

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "File extension not allowed here";    
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.Cancel = true;
```

This is new to SharePoint 2010. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg981880.aspx#UsingEventReceiversInSPFPart2_CancelingAndRedirecting)

EDIT:
You can also block files of certain types at Web Application Level (without custom code), if that works for you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I tried as you said. but no luck. ItemAdding event receiver for document library is behaving differently

Comment: see my updated snippets. ALso do not call base.ItemAdding after you set the error message, status and cancel property.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(allowed file types checking) // your file type checking
{
    //allowed file types
}
else
{
    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
    properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/error_Custom.aspx?Error=" + "Your error Message";
    //if you create any custom error page 
    this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
}
```