# Control the type of Document Uploaded

Tags: document-library

How do I control the type of document (only .docx allowed) is being uploaded in one of the SharePoint 2010 document libraries?

Comment: Already answered http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-to-restrict-a-document-library-to-a-specific-file-type-extension

Answer (score 1):

Through central administration you can block upload file types.

central admin -> Operations -> Blocked FileTypes -> now select the site and add the extension you want to block.

you can read on this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288335(v=office.12).aspx

or as hugh stated have an eventReciver to handle it for selected document libraryies only

[Preventing document Uploading to Document Library in SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24514/preventing-document-uploading-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-2010)